# need to search an entire array not just one

Tags: c#, arrays, string, visual-studio-2010, class

sorry for asking too much question but I have a problem when I'm comparing string to string in array it will only search for one instance of the array, for example  the program allows you to add patients to an array but when I used the compare string it will only compare to the last added patient, can you help me?

this is my program:

```
     public class Patient
    {
        public string patientidString;
        public string firstNameString;
        public string lastNameString;
        public string dateString;

        public Patient()
        {
            patientidString = "";
            firstNameString = "";
            lastNameString = "";
            dateString = "";
        }

        public Patient(string idValue, string firstNameVal, string lastNameVal, string dateVal)
        {
            patientidString = idValue;
            firstNameString = firstNameVal;
            lastNameString = lastNameVal;
            dateString = dateVal;
        }

    }


    //Array
    Patient[] patientInfo = new Patient[10];


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < patientInfo.Length; ++i)
        patientInfo[i] = new Patient();
        try
        {
            foreach (Patient patientinfoIndex in patientInfo)

            patientInfo[itemCountInteger].patientidString = textBox1.Text;
            patientInfo[itemCountInteger].firstNameString = textBox2.Text;
            patientInfo[itemCountInteger].lastNameString = textBox3.Text;
            patientInfo[itemCountInteger].dateString = dateTimePicker1.Text;

            string names = patientInfo[itemCountInteger].patientidString + "  " + patientInfo[itemCountInteger].firstNameString + " " + patientInfo[itemCountInteger].lastNameString;
            listBox1.Items.Add(names);
            itemCountInteger++;
            listBox1.SelectedItem = names;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Contacts are limited to 20. Please delete some contacts prior to adding more.");
        }

    }


    //Search Button search a patients id and display his surname in the label if patient is found  display his surname and name
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int intTest = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < patientInfo.Length; x++)
        {
            if (textBox4.Text == patientInfo[x].patientidString)
            {
                label6.Text = (patientInfo[x].firstNameString + "  " + patientInfo[x].lastNameString);
                PatientForm patientform = new PatientForm();
                patientform.Show();
                patientform.label6.Text = (patientInfo[x].patientidString);
                patientform.label7.Text = (patientInfo[x].firstNameString);
                patientform.label8.Text =(patientInfo[x].lastNameString);
                patientform.dateTimePicker1.Text = (patientInfo[x].dateString);
                intTest = 1;
            }

        }

        if (intTest == 0)
        {
            label6.Text = ("not found");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your `button1_Click` function is bound to an Add New Patient button.

The lines of code

```
for (int i = 0; i < patientInfo.Length; ++i)
    patientInfo[i] = new Patient();
```

are clearing out all the patient data you have entered previously every time you add a new patient!  That is why you are only ever finding the last patient you entered when you search.  You'll want to move those lines of code elsewhere, such as the constructor for your form class.

Comment: cant do that as i get error : cannot access a nonstatic member of outer type via nested type

Comment: @user3439080 Where did you move the code? Why do you have nested classes?

Comment: i try moving it to constructor patient and the one bellow

Comment: @user3439080 that code is calling the patient constructor, so you don't want to move it into the patient constructor.  You want to move it into the form class that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `foreach` loop you do not need to use an indexer,

```
foreach (Patient patientinfoIndex in patientInfo)
{
    patientinfoIndex.patientidString = textBox1.Text;
    patientinfoIndex.firstNameString = textBox2.Text;
    patientinfoIndex.lastNameString = textBox3.Text;
    patientinfoIndex.dateString = dateTimePicker1.Text;

    string names = 
        patientinfoIndex.patientidString + "  " + 
        patientinfoIndex.firstNameString + " " + 
        patientinfoIndex.lastNameString;

    listBox1.Items.Add(names);
    listBox1.SelectedItem = names;
}
```

You are also missing braces `{` `}`, which would cause the loop to only execute the first statement after the loop declaration, and not the rest.

Comment: if I take the idexes out the program wont know what patientString is plus if i add the brackes it will create 10 patients at once when button is clicked

Comment: I don't understand what you mean it will create 10 patients at once. Base on your code it is already doing that.

Answer (score 0):

after  `intTest = 1;` you need to break the `for` loop.

```
intTest = 1;
break;
```